# Superset handling missing values in time series - difference between bar chart and line chart

Tags: plot, charts, time-series, bar-chart, apache-superset

I'm plotting a time series chart with missing values.
The generated query looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', arrival_time) AS __timestamp,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM public.data
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', arrival_time);
```

When plotting a time series line chart, values are correctly positioned on the x axis according to their date value:
[image]
On the other hand, when I plot a bar chart, values are positioned by their index in the data, not by their date:
[image]

I can solve this by using the resample function (pick `1D`/`asfreq`), but I'm still wondering if there is a reason this works out of the box for the line chart but not for the bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to select the "Sort Bars" toggle on the customize tab. I speculate the reason why it is not sorted is that the bar chart is not time series. There is a time-series bar chart you can use instead if you don't want to toggle this button.

Comment: The X-values are sorted, they are just not aligned on the x axis according to their values but to their position in the ordering.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want a gap in the chart where data doesn't exist. If so, you want to use a "time-series bar chart". Try that out and let me know if that answers your question.